# How to play and record voice message without HTML5

Tags: javascript, java, webrtc

I want to play and record voice message without HTML5 because HTML5 is not supported for all browsers .

We are using JAVA and HTML here.
Can any one help, what are alternatives way to play and record a voice message. Currently i am using Applet for this, but due to several update in JDK we need to continuously change in code, so looking for alternative solutions.

Comment: if you can't use html5, and you can't use java, then you're basically limited to flash, which is a dead-end path as well.

Comment: Reason you can not use HTML5 features? Supporting out dated browsers?

Comment: I am no interested to use HTML 5 and applet. is there any options. like WebRTC or something else

Comment: If you're having support issues with HTML5, WebRTC is definitely not an option. WebRTC support is more limited than HTML5 by a long way http://caniuse.com/#search=webrtc

Comment: what you guys suggesting, to use HTML5 for this. but there are limitations with few browser.